# Finding exact row used in sapply in R

Tags: r, sapply

I would like to be able to see whether values in a column of a data frame are within the range of values in another dataframe in `R`. I can do that with sapply and put Yes and `NA` with ifelse. However, I want to be able to find out exactly which row numbers (and even better what content) of the first file was used for those Yes rows. In other words, I want to know the contents of second df matched to which columns of the first and then get the contents of a specific column in the first file.

This is what I am using:

```
cigar2_count$Visit1_counts <- ifelse(sapply(cigar2_count$HPV_Position, function(p) 
  any(cigar1_count$minV <= p & cigar1_count$maxV >= p)),"YES", NA)
```

This is what I want to be able to do but it gives me content of first file based on row numbers of the second one not actually what row in the first file corresponded to the second file.

```
cigar2_count$Visit1_counts <- ifelse(sapply(cigar2_count$HPV_Position, function(p) 
  any(cigar1_count$minV <= p & cigar1_count$maxV >= p)),cigar1_count$Unique_Read_Count, NA)
```

Here is a sample data:
First file: I made columns for the 500 range of HPV_Position and named those min and max
[image]

Second file:
[image]

These are just samples though. The actual files are much larger.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data would be helpful, as code is merely suggestive to the structure.

Comment: Sure. I just added some.

Comment: Thanks, but ... Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly. (And, to be honest, unless absolutely trivial, I'm not going to spend time *transcribing* data.)

Comment: maybe work in SQL, as this makes the structure much clearer?

Comment: Hi so I tried pasting the contents but it looks distorted. How can I paste it appropriately? or should I just upload some tables?

Comment: I don't know much SQL. Anyone have any ideas on this?